# Do Americans pronounce the letter "t" in the end of words like a "d"?

Tags: pronunciation

How do Americans pronounce the letter "t" in the end of words? Do they pronounce it like a "d"?

Comment: I think some examples narrowing down your question would be beneficial. I'm sure that a sentence such as "I like it" does not end in /d/.

Comment: This features is also sometimes found in the interior of words.

Comment: Examples, please.

Comment: @GEdgar I would say it’s _only_ found in the interior of words, never word-finally. _Bet_ and _bed_ are not homophones in any dialect of AmE that I’m familiar with, though _better_ and _bedder_ are in many.

Comment: @Janus: it definitely can be found on the end of words. For example, the /t/ in *I put it back*. Not at the end of phrases, though, or words pronounced by themselves, which may be what you were thinking of.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, that was sloppily worded. It’s only found in the interior of _pause units_ (i.e., a group of words said with no pause between them), before an unstressed syllable, regardless of the actual location in the individual word – even an initial _t_ can be reduced if the first syllable is completely unstressed, as in _to_ or _today_ (“I went there today” will often have a flapped _t_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I beg to differ from your original comment. Basically you've conceded that, yes, it's pronounced the same very, very often!

Comment: @Araucaria My first comment was the result of being distracted halfway through and forgetting to post the rest of it, noting that pauses and stress distribution are what matter, not words.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sure. It's still a good question: *How is word-final T pronounced in Gen Am?* . Reason is that a native speaker who hadn't investigated might reckon there was only one, or perhaps two ways. Of course there are about 7 or 8 major possibilites-due to /t/ being an alveolar consonant-including: a normal unvoiced alveolar plosive, a dental plosive, an ejective, no-audible release, a voiced tap, a complete elision, a glottal stop, being part of a coalescent assimilation. 'Course there are then probably another twenty to thirty allophones (nasalised tap, lateral release, glottal ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet .. reinforcement, nasal release etc, etc, etc ...)

Answer (score 2):

A "T" on the end of a word may be pronounced "D" if the following word begins with certain sounds and the words are being pronounced rapidly.  Peter Shor's example of "I put it back" is a good one.

Basically, if "put" is not for some reason being emphasized (as when your mother tells you "PUT ... IT ... BACK!!"), then the "T" sound in "put" is abbreviated -- the percussive "T" ending sound due to the tongue completely stopping air air flow does not occur because the mouth is already preparing to pronounce "it".

This is just normal speech, and is unlikely to vary much by dialect.